# comma operator usage with assignment operator in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() {

    int x  = 5;
    int y = 0;
    x++, y = x*x;
    printf("x is %d\n", x);
    printf("y is %d\n", y);

}
```

**Question:**
Why the output of the above code is:

```
x is 6
y is 36
```

instead of

```
x is 6
y is 25
```

?

**Reasoning:**
I am thinking it should be the latter because assignment operator has higher precedence than comma and therefore first an assignment to `y` should happen setting it to `25` and then `x` should be evaluated and set to `6`.

Comment: Please see [What does the comma operator `,` do in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18444099/1708801)

Comment: Why write code that you are unsure of what it will do?

Comment: What makes you think that precedence has anything to do with the order of evaluation? They're totally different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precedence has to do with the syntax tree of your program, not with how the program executes. What those precedence levels are doing is disambiguating between

```
x++, (y = x*x) /* this is how your programs gets parsed */
```

and

```
(x++ ,  y) = x*x  /* this is NOT how it is parsed */
```

After your program gets parsed, the execution rules for `,` state that expressions are evaluated from left to right so the `x++` gets run before the `y = x*x`. In the end, the `,` is very similar to a `;`, except that you can put it inside places that expect expressions instead of statements.

Answer (score 3):

The LHS of the comma operator has to be evaluated before the RHS of the comma operator; there is a full sequence point between the two.

Therefore, `x++` has to be evaluated and all side-effects (the increment) must take place before the `y = x * x` part of the expression is considered or any part of it evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

The precedence doesn't determine the order of evaluation. `=` binds highly than `,` so the expression is:

```
(x++), ( y = x*x;)
```

Comma is evaluated left to right and includes a sequence point so your expression is similar to:

```
x++ ; y = x*x ;
```